# Search between two dates and populate datagrid with dates in between from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

so I'm kind of stuck, I want to create a form which allows the user to select a date and then pick a second date and the system will populate the DataGridView with all the event dates in between the two dates. I've looked at tutorials online but they all use sql and not xml.

The perfect scenario should be a user picks date1 and then picks date2, the system retrieves the dates from xml which are in between date1 to date2 and populates the information on the DataGridView.

can you please give a code for example as well.

Comment: A new to see sample of xml with a few repetitive nodes.

Comment: any chance of just an example

Comment: There are too many different styles of xml files to just randomly give an example that has nothing to do with your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need get the result that between date1 and date2.

Second, you need create a dynamic datatable according the result.

Finally, you could show the correspond data in the datagirdview.

The following is a code example.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime formatter = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        DateTime latter = dateTimePicker2.Value;
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\t.xml");
        var result = (from x in doc.Descendants("Student")
                     where Convert.ToDateTime(x.Element("Date").Value) <= latter && Convert.ToDateTime(x.Element("Date").Value) >= formatter
                     select x).ToList();
        List<string> column = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in result.Elements())
        {
            column.Add(item.Name.ToString());
        }
        column=column.Distinct().ToList();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (var item in column)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(item.Element("Name").Value, item.Element("Date").Value, item.Element("Age").Value);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;



    }
```

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School>
  <Student>
    <Name>test1</Name>
    <Date>2019-01-02</Date>
    <Age>21</Age>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Name>test2</Name>
    <Date>2019-03-01</Date>
    <Age>22</Age>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Name>test3</Name>
     <Date>2019-07-01</Date>
      <Age>22</Age>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Name>test4</Name>
     <Date>2019-10-05</Date>
     <Age>23</Age>
  </Student>
  <Student>
     <Name>test5</Name>
     <Date>2019-11-01</Date>
     <Age>24</Age>
  </Student>
</School>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: just posted my xml file

Comment: I have provided the xml I write, if you want to use your xml, you can refer to the code I write.

Comment: what is XDocument?

Comment: You can refer to [XDocument Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8).